# The way to put SupportMapFragment to another Fragment with overriding onCreateView()

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-support-library

I'll try to describe my situation:

I have `MyFragment extends Fragment` with overriding `onCreateView()`.

In `MyFragment.java`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
        //some manipulation with view
        return view;
```

in `my_fragment.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
       .....
  >
  <com.example.widgets.MyMapWidget
                   android:id="@+id/my_map"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="300dp"
                   />
 </LinearLayout>
```

in `MyMapWidget.java`

```
public class MyMapWidget extends LinearLayout {

  public MyMapWidget(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
       ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.widget_map, this, true);
...
}
```

in `widget_map.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
             >
        <!-- Some another views-->
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:id="@+id/my_map_fragment"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       />
       <!-- Some another views-->
</LinearLayout>
```

When I first time show `MyFragment` - all works great. But if then I show another fragment (with cleaning back stack) and then `MyFragment` again - I got `Inflate Exception`

```
Stacktrase

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #151: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at `com.***.****.fragments.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:78)`
```

Line #78 in `MyFragment.java` (method `onCreateView`)

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
```

Removing `MyMapWidget` from `my_fragment.xml` solved problem. But I have some questions:

1. Why it happens?
2. Can I show map like this?
3. May be you know another way how present map like part of the own `Fragment`?

NOTE: I checked answer on similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13906015/1616443), but can't solve my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the map in it's own fragment like this:

```
public class GoogleMapFragment extends MapFragment {

private static final String SUPPORT_MAP_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapOptions";

public GoogleMapFragment() {
    mCallback = null;
}

public static interface OnGoogleMapFragmentListener {
    void onMapReady(GoogleMap map);
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

public static GoogleMapFragment newInstance() {
    return new GoogleMapFragment();
}

public static GoogleMapFragment newInstance(GoogleMapOptions options) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putParcelable(SUPPORT_MAP_BUNDLE_KEY, options);

    GoogleMapFragment fragment = new GoogleMapFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnGoogleMapFragmentListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().getClass().getName()
                + " must implement OnGoogleMapFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (mCallback != null) {
        mCallback.onMapReady(getMap());
    }
    return view;
}

private OnGoogleMapFragmentListener mCallback;
}
```

And add it to your activity like this:

```
 // create a new map
 mapsFragment = GoogleMapFragment.newInstance();

 // Then we add it using a FragmentTransaction.
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mapsFragment, FRAGMENT_MAP_TAG);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Let your activity implement **OnGoogleMapFragmentListener**, then when the map is added and ready the following method will be called:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
       //add markers or whatever
}
```

Hope this is useful for you to get a bit more control over your mapfragment.

Answer (score 2):

I remember facing a similar issue a time ago. What worked for me is programmatically creating the map inside the fragment `onCreateView` method. Something like.-

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState, R.layout.fragment_layout);
    setupMap(); 
    return view;
}

private void setupMap() {
    mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    ParentActivity activity = getParentActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.wrapperMapPlaces, mapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, how solve it:

1. Detect event where `MyFragment` destroyed their view (`onDestroyView`)
2. In this method get instance of the `MyMapWidget` and call `destroyMap`.
3. `myMapWidget.destroyMap` will be:

   public void destroyMap(FragmentManager fm){
           fm.beginTransaction().remove(mMapFragment).commit();
   }

Just remove fragment with map, when parent fragment destroed their view.