# Xamarin.Android : Android.Views.InflateException in MapFragment when launched second time

Tags: xml, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the android map to locate the specified address. I am able to locate and mark the address on map for the first time successfully. But when I try to locate the another address it throws an Exception in the fragment :

> Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

**axml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/myMap"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

The problem is that when the fragment is replaced for the second time to locate new address, android is unable to inflate from axml. It crashes on line:

```
view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.map_layout, null);
```

[image]

I gone through these links, but could find the solution:

[Android map v2 error on second inflating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905977/android-map-v2-error-on-second-inflating)

[Android - SupportMapFragment error when openning for second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722851/android-supportmapfragment-error-when-openning-for-second-time)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7378/google-maps-wont-work-error-on-fragmenttransaction

I also tried using `SupportMapFragment`, behaviour is same.

Comment: try this [demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/) in the BasicDemoActivity with `MapFragment`

Comment: Can you add more code regarding your fragment transaction or upload a mvce(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your post? My guess is that you need to swap the fragment using `replace()` or to reuse the fragment and not inflate. Otherwise you need to use `ChildFragmentMananger` if you have a `fragment` inside a `fragment`

Comment: Jon: Possibly, your opinion of swapping the fragment is right. But instead of that, I found another way of doing. I have updated the answer. Could please post any reference to understand this concept of replace(), reusing the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after searching a lot I found the solution. Instead of using MapFragment, I used the MapView. Following is my code :

**axml layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/myMap"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView" />
```

**Fragment code:**

```
public class MapViewFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.map_layout, null);
        // Now this line works fine without throwing Inflate Exception
    }
}
```